# if-condition with characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I check if a character of a string is equal to another character? In my example below, which should find the position of a character in a string, my first method does not work. Why?

```
txt = "Hello World"
CharacterToFind = 'W'
#returns position of first appearance of charater in string
#returns -1 if character is not found

#this does not work:
for k in range(len(txt)): 
    print(k, txt[k])
    j=-1
    if(txt[k] == CharacterToFind): #this line likely contains the error
        j=k
print(j)

#this works:
l=txt.find(CharacterToFind)
print(l)
```

Comment: Initialize `j` before the `for` loop. It gets set to `-1` after the `W` in your example. For better understanding, use `Hello W` as the input.

Comment: 1) it doesn't work because you never told Python that `txt.find()` should be a function that executes your for loop. 2) you can't do that because strings are a built-in object and you can't add methods or attributes to them 3) the correct way is to do `def find(character_to_find):` then do your for loop and `return j` at the end. 4) we name variables and functions using `lower_case_with_underscores` not `CapitalizedLetters`, that's for classes.

Comment: also, next time you ask a question, please post the full error. Don't just say "it doesn't work" and make us guess. Say what the code should do and what it actually does.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and help! Though my error was to put j=-1 before the for-loop I have learned a lot of more from your answers!

Answer (score 0):

It's best to just use:

```
print(txt.find(char_to_find))
```

But if you want to do it with a loop for practise, this is a nice way:

```
txt = "Hello World"
char_to_find = 'W'

for i, char in enumerate(txt):
    if char == char_to_find:
        print(i)
        break
else:
    # will run if loop didn't break
    print(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3


txt = "Hello World"
CharacterToFind = 'W'

for index, character in enumerate(txt):
    if character == CharacterToFind:
        print(index, character)
        break


for index in range(len(txt)):
    if txt[index] == CharacterToFind:
        print(index, txt[index])
        break

if CharacterToFind in txt:
    print(CharacterToFind)
```

Function based solution:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

txt = "Hello World"
CharacterToFind = 'W'


def try_to_find(CharacterToFind, txt):
    for index in range(len(txt)):
        if txt[index] == CharacterToFind:
            return (index, txt[index])
    return -1


result = try_to_find(CharacterToFind, txt)
if result:
    print(result)
```

More complex solution to find all matches in the list. Also good example to understand `yield`

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

txt = "Hello World"
CharacterToFind = 'o'


def try_to_find_v1(CharacterToFind, txt):
    for index in range(len(txt)):
        if txt[index] == CharacterToFind:
            yield (index, txt[index])
    yield -1

results = []
find_gen = try_to_find_v1(CharacterToFind, txt)
while True:
    res = next(find_gen)
    if res == -1:
        break
    else:
        results.append(res)

print("\nv1")
if len(results) > 0:
    print(results)
else:
    print(-1)


def try_to_find_v2(CharacterToFind, txt):
    for index in range(len(txt)):
        if txt[index] == CharacterToFind:
            yield (index, txt[index])


results = []
find_gen = try_to_find_v2(CharacterToFind, txt)
while True:
    try:
        results.append(next(find_gen))
    except StopIteration:
        break

print("\nv2")
if len(results) > 0:
    print(results)
else:
    print(-1)
```

Output:

```
v1
[(4, 'o'), (7, 'o')]

v2
[(4, 'o'), (7, 'o')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you have defined `j=-1` inside the for loop because of which every single time your loop runs it overwrites the value stored in the variable `j`.

The solution is defining `j` outside the loop as done below:

```
txt = "Hello World"
CharacterToFind = 'W'
j = -1
for k in range(len(txt)): 
    print(k, txt[k])
    if(txt[k] == CharacterToFind):
        j=k
print(j)
```